# Designing a database for a business context involving orders, payment methods and shipping addresses

Tags: database-design, normalization

Our group has been developing a webapp to take it live in the future. We got stuck at normalizing a few tables, as it could involve redundancy.

We have some tables that I describe as follows:

1. shipping table: the address attributes and ID being the primary key.
2. order table: few attributes along with address attributes and oID being the primary key.
3. payment/card table: few attributes along with address attributes and pID being the primary key.

Is this in normalized state or do we have redundancy here?

Comment: You may want to check out [Marc Rettig's 5 Rules of Data Normalization](http://informationqualitysolutions.com/FreeStuff/rettigNormalizationPoster.pdf) to clarify what you need to be doing when normalizing your data.

Comment: Review [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226201/is-it-worth-breaking-out-address-information-into-a-separate-database-table/17233857#17233857) on Stack Overflow.  The short answer is that no, you should not worry about redundancy here. These different entities have addresses, that is just a coincidence.  They aren't the same data points (at least as far as your system is concerned).  Unless you mean to actually manage _locations_ as it's own thing in your system, there's no advantage to splitting addresses away from these tables.

Answer (score 1):

So you have several tables each of which holds an address. You're wondering if these common address-related columns should be in their own table.

The typical answer is "yes" - a separate would be a good idea. There are [any number of posts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=address%20normalization) on this subject on this site.

If you do make a common address table will you compare user input to existing rows so you can re-use an existing address_id in one of your tables? If the answer is "no", or you don't have a plan to handle small variations in how the user spells or formats the address, then why bother?